# Can't see on PC a CSV file saved from android database

Tags: android

In my app I'm exporting a sqlite database as CSV to the externalStorage. When I open a file explorer on the device, I can see the CSV file and I can also see it through the eclipse DDMS, even pull it using adb. But when I connect the device to a PC as a USB Mass Stograge device, the file doesn't appear.

Is this normal? is there a way to make this file visible when connected as Mass Storage device?

Comment: Are you saving the file with getExternalStorage() path?

Comment: Toggle the USB Media mode and camera mode and see if you can see it..It happened with me too after toggling it worked...

Comment: I'm saving with getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: Toggled Usb Media and Camera mode, still can't see it

Answer (score 1):

After saving the file, tell the MediaScanner about the newly file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137966/import-and-export-csv-file-in-android)

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, new String[] { filename }, null, null);
```

Comment: Using that line I can see now the file on my PC, but the file appears as 0kB (it appears as 864kB in phone file explorer), do you know why is this happening? Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue sometimes when taking screenshots on the phone - didn't found a solution, but it may be a different problem. Have you tried flushing/closing BEFORE scanFile?

Comment: btw. it DOES matter in which directory you stored the file, because the MediaScanner will handle the file depending on the directory it is stored in. So Files in 'Pictures'-Folder are treated like Image Media.
I used the DCIM Folder which seems to be 'undefined'
Let me know if this worked, so I can update the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I placed the file on the downloads directory using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) and now it works, I can see it and open it in my pc without trouble. Thanks again.