# Import and export CSV file in android

Tags: android

I have an app where I want to be able to export to/import from CSV Files.

In a Use-Case I want to export data into a CSV File, connect the phone to a PC and edit the CSV there and re-import the file afterwards back into the app.

I am currently using a Motorola Razor I (latest android version) and no matter where I try to save the file, it does not appear to be public when connecting the phone to a computer (it's not there)

I can see the file on the android File Browser itself, so it is there, but in Windows Explorer the file is not there.

What would be a proper way to implement such a feature:

- Export to CSV
- Edit on Computer
- Reimport same file

I've used function `getExternalDirectory()` and have also tried `getExternalDirectoryPublic()` - in either cases the file doesn't appear on the computer.

Any hints highly appreciated!

Comment: Use opencsv to deal with importing and exporting of data. And for the sake for starting it up you can use this link http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/read-write-csv-file-in-java-using-opencsv-library/

Comment: My problem is not generating the CSV - but **WHERE** to place it, so I can access it from the computer when the phone is connected. I just want to be able to open it from the computer, but I cannot get it to be visible in Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems, I missed something in order to make the file appear on the computer. Thing is, android treats the files not directly, but the MediaScanner does - so all I had to do is tell the MediaScanner about the new File and it works!

Writing the File with `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` and after the file is saved call

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, new String[] { filename }, null, null);
```

to tell the MediaScanner about the newly file

Hopefully anyone find it useful